# Create a component programmatically in Nativescript Angular

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

How do I programmatically create a Component and get a View object to add inside a StackLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the documentation for this to be woefully inadequate.  The best is in version 1 of [The NativeScript Book](https://nativescript.org/get-the-nativescript-book/#).  As I recall, version 2 dropped this chapter.  If you can't find version 1 anywhere send me a message and I'll send you the .pdf file I saved.

Comment: I have had any luck finding V1. Is possible to send the pdf, would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'll get that to you a little later today.

Comment: @MatthewDennis Send me an email and I'l send you a link to the book.  (Your email is not attached to your SO profile, or I'd send it to you directly).  Since the book is copyrighted I prefer not to post the link publicly.  You want Appendix D.  It's not in Angular, and their code uses a GridLayout rather than StackLayout, but you'll see the concepts and their explanations.  That was enough for me when I created two different custom UI components.